# How run Linux application from a mounted Windows disk?

Tags: linux, mount, symlink, executable

I have dual-boot operating system, Ubuntu and Windows 7. The problem is I can't install some Linux application on my Linux because considering the disk space. I always regret to myself why I allocated small space for my Linux. My friend told me that I can run Linux application from a mounted disk (Windows).

The idea, for example installing NetBeans IDE. I download and install it to mounted disk (Windows) from my Linux. And then, I create a `symlink` to the application where is installed. I just run its executable on Linux when it finishes.

But, I really doubt about myself that it really works. If that really works, how can I do that?

I have been known some basics about Linux.

Comment: You are almost certainly trying to solve the wrong problem.  If you can afford to shrink your windows partition a bit you would be better off using `gparted` to do that and to move and enlarge your linux filesystem.  Search here for gparted and see also http://gparted.org/

Comment: I agree with cas on this being a better (but less fun and educational) approach. And use a filesystem understood by both to share common files, like music (for win7 that would be: fat32, ntfs, exfat; for win8 you have to format in the old format if you choose ntfs).

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's something like WINE (which is for running windows binaries in linux) for running linux binaries in windows, you probably need to create a virtual machine.

A virtual machine has its own operating system, which either means using up more space from your windows disk/partition, or using your normal bare-metal linux installation also in a virtual machine. There are challenges associated with that, but may be easy enough. Also, some virtual machine managers such as virtualbox make it a bit more work to use ["raw disks"](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk) such as your other partitions.

An example issue you might face: The bare-metal linux would have used a driver like intel/radeon/nouveau for the graphics card in Xorg, and would be configured in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, and if you boot a VM instead, it might need another driver set instead. You can make a config that has both so it will boot on either the VM or bare-metal, or reconfigure it each time you boot it differently.

Another example would be if you have things like `/dev/sda1` in your `/etc/fstab` file, and then you have to make that a raw disk, then the virtual machine won't see `/dev/sda1` but `/dev/sda` instead. To fix that you should use the UUID syntax in fstab. replace `/dev/sda1` with `UUID=xxxx-xxxxxx-...` which you should get from the `blkid` command.

Before you try anything new and complicated you don't understand, be sure to have backups.

Comment: He is describing a disk space issue, not a other-os-binaries issue.

Comment: @ivanivan he's talking about failing to allocate enough space; but without any partitioning changes, he can put a VM on some extra free space he has in windows

Answer (score 0):

It's a horrible, horrible hack and kittens will die in the process, but it's possible to create a large empty file on the windows partition, format it as for instance ext4 or XFS, then mount it somewhere and copy (`cp -a`) over *everything* from `/usr` (or another directory of your choosing, the one that takes the most disk space, perhaps `/home`), then mount the disk image file as `/usr`. Then you can delete the old `/usr` directory (from the original partition) once everything is working, and you end up with more disk space. Remember to copy over files with the correct file permissions. Also remember to set up the new `/usr` mount in `/etc/fstab`.

**BUT**, this is a horrible, horrible hack. Don't do it. Rather repartition and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Download LinuxMint live disk for your cpu (amd64 probably?).  Boot with that, open a terminal, run `sudo gparted` and resize your partitions.  Works best when Windows is completely shut down, no updates in progress, etc. and doing a cold boot.

Alternatively, as suggested in another answer, you can create a file system somewhere - install a new disk, get an external USB drive, or even create a sparse file on your Windows partition and make a file system on it (but if you can do this, just resize the partition!).  Then boot with the Mint disk again, mount what your installed root (/) the new file system are on, copy/move files, and make an appropriate entry in the /etc/fstab of your installed system.